# More checkbox in a row of a listView

Tags: android, json, listview, checkbox

I'd like to know if it is possible to show more checkboxes in a single row of a listView like this 
[image]

I had already displayed the question but i don't know how to put there the checkboxes.

I was thinking of using a custom view but the problem is that the number of checkboxes is defined by an array in jsonObject like this and iI don't know how to do it

```
{
    "error": false,
    "question": {
        "idQuestion": "11435",
        "type": "MC",
        "extra": "",
        "fkLanguage": "1",
        "translation": "Electromagnetic radiation (light) holds energy. Which one of the following statements is correct?<\/P>",
        "answer": "",
        "0": [{
            "idAnswer": "49220",
            "score": "0",
            "fkQuestion": "11435",
            "fksub": null,
            "fkAnswer": "49220",
            "fkLanguage": "1",
            "translation": "Infrared radiation is richer in energy than visible radiation."
        }, {
            "idAnswer": "49221",
            "score": "0",
            "fkQuestion": "11435",
            "fksub": null,
            "fkAnswer": "49221",
            "fkLanguage": "1",
            "translation": "Infrared radiation is richer in energy than ultraviolet radiation."
        }, {
            "idAnswer": "49222",
            "score": "0",
            "fkQuestion": "11435",
            "fksub": null,
            "fkAnswer": "49222",
            "fkLanguage": "1",
            "translation": "Visible radiation is richer in energy than ultraviolet radiation."
        }, {
            "idAnswer": "49223",
            "score": "1",
            "fkQuestion": "11435",
            "fksub": null,
            "fkAnswer": "49223",
            "fkLanguage": "1",
            "translation": "Ultraviolet radiation is richer in energy than visible radiation."
        }]
    }
}
```

The checkbox has to display the answer but when I control what checkbox is checked I have to take 'idAnswer' provided in the array

Comment: `int numQuestions = jsonObject.getJSONArray("0").getLength()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use CustomListviews.
custom listview can customize the row of the list.

1. **you need to define a child layout that containing required number of
   elements (this  case checkboxes and a textview).**
2. **you need a model class.**
3. **Adapter class which extends base adapter or
       arrayadapter.**

you can refer from this links

[AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

[simplifiedCoding](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-custom-listview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a RecyclerView adapter with two types {Questions and answers}. So you inject to the adapter an arraylist of your generic object. If the current object is a Question you must inflate the Question layout and if the object is an answer you inflate the answer layout. Look any example of the use of getViewByType. Your arraylist could be something like [question, answer, answer, question, answer, answer, answer...]